# OpenCV Python: Detecting lines only in ROI

Tags: python, opencv, houghlinesp

I'd like to detect lines inside a region of interest. My output image should display the original image and the detected lines in the selected ROI. So far it has not been a problem to find lines in the original image or select a ROI but finding lines only inside the ROI did not work. My MWE reads an image, converts it to grayscale and lets me select a ROI but gives an error when `HoughLinesP` wants to read `roi`.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('example.jpg',1)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img ,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Select ROI
fromCenter = False
roi = cv2.selectROI(gray, fromCenter)

# Crop ROI
roi = img[int(roi[1]):int(roi[1]+roi[3]), int(roi[0]):int(roi[0]+roi[2])]

# Find lines
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 30
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(roi,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for x in range(0, len(lines)):
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[x]:
        cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(237,149,100),2)

cv2.imshow('Image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The console shows:

> lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(roi,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
>
> error: OpenCV(3.4.1)
>   C:\Miniconda3\conda-bld\opencv-suite_1533128839831\work\modules\imgproc\src\hough.cpp:441:
>   error: (-215) image.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) <<
>   3)) in function cv::HoughLinesProbabilistic

My assumption is that `roi` does not have the correct format. I am using Python 3.6 with Spyder 3.2.8.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `cv2.HoughLinesP` is expecting a single-channel image, so the cropped region could be taken from the gray image and that would remove the error:

```
# Crop the image
roi = list(map(int, roi)) # Convert to int for simplicity
cropped = gray[roi[1]:roi[1]+roi[3], roi[0]:roi[0]+roi[2]]
```

Note that I'm changing the output name from `roi` to `cropped`, and that's because you're going to still need the `roi` box.  The points `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2` are pixel positions in the cropped image, not the full image.  To get the images drawn correctly, you can just add the upper left corner pixel position from `roi`. 
 Here's the for loop with relevant edits:

```
# Find lines
minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 30
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped,1,np.pi/180,100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)
for x in range(0, len(lines)):
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in lines[x]:
        cv2.line(img,(x1+roi[0],y1+roi[1]),(x2+roi[0],y2+roi[1]),(237,149,100),2)
```

Comment: Changing the coordinates of `cv2.line` makes sense, thanks for that! `cropped` and `gray` are both arrays of `dtype=uint8` only differing in length but `cv2.HoughLinesP(gray,...)` delivers coordinates of detected lines whereas `cv2.HoughLinesP(cropped,...)` just returns `None`. Do you have any idea where to find my mistake?

Comment: That just means no lines were found in the crop.  You can add `if lines is not None:` before the for loop to protect against this error.  You can try changing the parameters (`minLineLength`, `maxLineGap`, etc.) if you think there should have been lines detected.  Also, in your post you say you want to run `HoughLinesP` on the image, but it could help to run it on a canny edge detection image [like shown in this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works after also adjusting `rho` value inside `HoughLinesP`. It does not find as many lines as I want it to but for now my question is answered. The input image is already a canny edge detection image.